# When I click the download button it will decode all the content, it does not download in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

View page

```
<?php
    $path=$post->file_path;
    $path1=base64_encode($path);
?>
<p>Download uploaded file</p>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/fileupload/download/'.$path1);?>">Download</a>
```

My controller page

```
public function download($path1)
{
    $path2=base64_decode($path1);
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $data=file_get_contents($path2);
    $name='Tulips.jpg';
    force_download($name,$data);
}
```

As mentioned in the title, when I click the download button it will decode all the content, it does not download in codeigniter.

Please help me out, I am stuck with this problem last two days.

Comment: are you getting any error message or not?

Comment: Is it ok base_url('index.php/fileupload/download/'.$path1); ???

Comment: Am getting encoded output...it wil not download the file

Comment: Yes tats fyn.It wil work